# CRM Context Object persists connection even when creating new instance

Tags: c#, wcf, dynamics-crm, crm

I have a system in place for a WCF Service, in which I take in some credentials from the client. I then try to authenticate with CRM using these credentials. If the authentication fails, I use a pre-defined service account, with the credentials stored in web.config.

What I have found is, no matter what, the first set of credentials used persists for any further requests, no matter how much I tear down the first object. I even instantiate new objects, wrap each context in a `using` statement, etc.

I have watered the code down into a simple 'connect, retry' block, and this suffers the same issue. The code is as follows:

```
try
{
    var connection = new CrmConnection();
    connection.ServiceUri = new Uri("https://my.crm.dynamics.com/");
    connection.ClientCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
    connection.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "removed1";
    connection.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "removed1";

    using (var crm = new CrmOrganizationServiceContext(connection))
    {
        var req = new Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.WhoAmIRequest();
        var resp = (Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.WhoAmIResponse)crm.Execute(req);
    }
}

catch (Exception ex) { }

try
{
    var connection = new CrmConnection();
    connection.ServiceUri = new Uri("https://my.crm.dynamics.com/");
    connection.ClientCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
    connection.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "removed2";
    connection.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "removed2";

    using (var crm = new CrmOrganizationServiceContext(connection))
    {
        var req = new Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.WhoAmIRequest();
        var resp = (Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.WhoAmIResponse)crm.Execute(req);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) { }
```

Assume that `removed1` is incorrect and `removed2` is correct. The second call will fail instantly with a token exception, saying invalid credentials. If `removed1` is correct, and `removed2` is not, the first will authenticate and get the `WhoAmIRequest` fine. Then, removed2 should fail, but it does not, as it seems to still hold the connection using the old credentials. The invalid credentials still allows the service to make requests. Not good!

The bizarre thing is, the code for the authentication is in a separate project. I have included this project in a simple console application, and everything works fine. I can only assume this is something to do with the WCF service and the way it holds connections. I've tried manually disposing, calling garbage collection, setting to null, etc. I've also tried using web config connection strings called by name (hard coded 2 test ones), tried manually creating the connection string settings with unique names, using `CrmConnection.Parse()`, etc.

I have even copy pasted the code i'm using directly into a console application, and it works fine. Due to this, I am convinced it is to do with the behavior of a WCF service, and not the code itself. I set the class to have the behavior of

`[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]`

But no luck. If it is of any importance, this code is running in a message inspector class which implements `IDispatchMessageInspector`.

How can I ensure that I can get a fresh session? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the default constructor of the `CrmConnection` class. When doing that, your connection is cached by name. This name is supposed to be the name of the `ConnectionStringSettings`, but using this constructor that property is never being set and keeps its default value, thus always returning the first connection object created.

Just use another overload of the constructors, e.g. that using a connection string or accepting the service url, credentials etc.

The `CrmConnection` class was designed to offer an easy way to create connectionstrings in config files, similar to database connection strings. It had its issues and has been removed from the Dynamics CRM 2016 SDK.

Comment: I have replaced the `new CrmConnection()` with `CrmConnection.Parse(connString)`, with the connection string being the standard `Url=A;User=B;Password=C;`. However, the same issue still occurring. Does the caching occur even using `CrmConnection.Parse(str)`? As I don't know the username/password until runtime, I can't call a connection string by name. Thanks.

Comment: Just to confirm, I did as you said and used two completely different connection strings and called them in the constructor of a new `CrmConnection`. The same problem still occurs.